# Anyway to prove the optimality of a mixed integer nonlinear programming (MINLP)

Tags: convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Consider a MINLP, call it $P_0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{x,y} & ~~f(x,y) \\
\text{s.t.} &~~ g(x,y)\leq0 \\
& ~~x\geq 0 \\
& ~~y = 0 ~\text{or} ~1,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $x$ and $y$ are vectors here. The problem is convex after relaxing the binary constraint to $0\leq y\leq 1$. Let the optimal solution of the relaxed convex optimization problem be $x',y'$. I found that most of the entries in $y'$ are actually binary (only a few entries are fractional). If I just simply round these fractional entries in $y'$ and leave the binary entries unchanged, it leads to a binary vector, say $y''$. Now I end up solving the following optimization problem, call it $P_1$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{x} & ~~f(x,y'') \\
\text{s.t.} &~~ g(x,y'')\leq0 \\
& ~~x\geq 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Assume $P_1$ always has a feasible solution, I feel the optimal solution of $P_1$ might be the same as the optimal solution in $P_0$ based on some simulation results. Or if they are not equivalent, the optimal objective value of $P_1$ should be very close to the one in $P_0$. Any idea to analytically prove the optimality of a MINLP or how close these two solutions are? Any reference or paper is appreciated.

Comment: There is no certificate of optimality for mixed integer problems. You need to enumerate all possible combinations of integer solutions and solve the corresponding problems (or use a structured method like branch&bound or cutting planes) to prove optimality of a problem with integer variables.

Answer (score 2):

LinAlg is correct. There's really nothing theoretical to offer here; everything is heuristic. In fact, you *cannot* assume that $y''$ and the true optimum $y^*$ coincide *even on those values for which* $y''_i=0$ or $y''_i=1$.

All you really know at this point is this:
$$f(x',y') \leq f(x^*,y^*) \leq f(x'',y'')$$
where $(x^*,y^*)$ is the true optimum. If the gap $f(x'',y'')-f(x',y')$ is small, then you know you're close. If it's not, then you're going to have to do something to improve it.

One relatively simple way to tighten your bound is to generate *multiple* test vectors $y''$, solving your second problem with each, and taking the best result. A simple approach is probabilistic: for each element $y''_i$, set it to 1 with a probability $y'_i$, and 0 otherwise. Of course, this means that $y''_i=y'_i$ if $y'_i\in\{0,1\}$; and as I said above, you cannot be sure that will be the case for the true optimum $y^*_i$. Nevertheless, you're likely to see *some* improvement this way.

Short of that, if you want to improve your result, you're simply going to have to employ some sort of intelligent exhaustive search, such as a branch and bound method. There are certainly plenty of rigorous treatments out there in libraries and the internet, but I've taught from [Stephen Boyd's EE364b notes (PDF)](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/bb_slides.pdf) before and found them to be a nicely accessible introduction to the basics.